# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection for unique compound index including an ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

collection index schema and index:

```
const schema: Mongoose.SchemaDefinition = {
  field_name: { type: String, required: true },
  mask: { type: String, required: true },
  value: { type: String, required: true },
  register: { type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'register' }
};

const indexFields = {
  field_name: 1,
  mask: 1,
  regsiter: 1,
  value: 1
};

export const RegisterFieldsSchema = new Mongoose
  .Schema(schema, { timestamps: true })
  .index(indexFields, {unique: true});
```

And the collection already has records with same `field`, `mask` and `value` as following record, but no record contains the same `register`.

When I try to insert a document:

```
db.getCollection('registerfields')
.insert({
    "field_name":"ARM_SMMU_CBn_PMEVTYPER2_0_NSU",
    "mask":"0x10000000",
    "register":ObjectId("5ae2639ffc61a6c8dbb332a5"),
    "value":"0x00000000",
});
```

database returns:

```
grdb-dev.registerfields index: 
field_name_1_mask_1_regsiter_1_value_1 dup key: 
{
    : "ARM_SMMU_CBn_PMEVTYPER2_0_NSU", 
    : "0x10000000", 
    : null, 
    : "0x00000000"
}
```

According to several other answers, this might caused by a document without `register` property already existed in the collection. So I checked if this is the case:

```
db.getCollection('registerfields')
    .find({"register":  {$exists: false}})
```

result: `Fetched 0 record(s) in 6ms`

I also run the above query to check if all documents contains `field_name`, `mask` and `value`. Got 0 record for all of

Anyone know why the duplicate key has null for register?

Comment: What about `.find({ "field_name": "ARM_SMMU_CBn_PMEVTYPER2_0_NSU" })` and what that shows you? Really the index creation should be failing so It's most logical to drop all indexes on the collection and then let them create again

Comment: I can got a record with a different ObjectId on register field. Seems mongo will treat ObjectId on compound key as a null.

Comment: I recreate the table every time but still facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB treat `ObjectId` on compound key as null. Cannot find a document about this problem, but that's the result of my tests on MongoDB 3.4.8.

I possible partial solution is using partial index on the field that might use `ObjectID` or save the string instead of the `ObjectId` object.

Reference: 
[Partial Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial)